# Unity colision trigger to start an animation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, animation

I need to write a C# script to make a character changed animation. Situation: User(VR user) get close and enter collision area of an npc, who is in sitting animation loop. Once user enter colision area of the npc, npc changes animation to "sit to stand" and from there a series of animations to get to another place. How do I edit this script to make sure the change of animation happen once collision area get triggered. This is a code I found from youtube turorial, It shows the user name once he enters into trigger zone. If needed more information let me know.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class sittingtrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        void onTriggerEnter(Collider other)
        { Debug.Log(other.name); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trigger method is a method called outside Update.

```
public class sittingtrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
    void onTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    { 
        Debug.Log(other.name); 
        //here you have to set the variables of your animator to trigger the animation
    }
}
```

Remember to set your trigger-zone-collider to "Is Trigger"!

Comment: What kind of variables do I use? (sorry if the questions seem foolish I am extremely new at this). I used mixamo for animations so I got those files imported into unity

Comment: Try this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JS4k_lwmZHk if doesn't work for you tell me and I'll update this answer okey? ^^

Answer (score 0):

Put the onTriggerEnter outside update like Lotal says.

Also just have an animator.

```
public Animator animator;
```

and set your animator in the inspector to to the slot on the script in unity editor.
Setup transitions from 'any state' in your animation state machine. Then you can do something like

```
animator.SetTrigger("StandAnimation");
```

In the state machine between any state and the new animation you click on the link and add a condition, in the parameters you should have created a trigger 'StandAnimation' then just set it in the condition. This is just an example you can use whatever names you want, you can also use int, bool, float instead of trigger.